# Prevent HTML Modal Dialog from Closing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, modal-dialog

I want to use the `<dialog>` HTML element to create a modal. I'm trying to restrict the user's ability to close the modal under some circumstances, and tried to call `e.preventDefault()` when the dialog's `onClose()` is fired, however, that doesn't stop the dialog from closing.

What is the intended way to control whether modal `dialog` can be closed or not?

```js
ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
      document.getElementById("root")
 );

function App() {
  const modalRef = React.createRef()
  
  function handleClose(e) { // press escape button to trigger this
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('closing')
  }
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <button 
        onClick={() => modalRef.current.showModal()}>
        Open modal
      </button>
      
      
      <dialog
        ref={modalRef}
        onClose={handleClose}>
        Hello world
      </dialog>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

```html
<div id='root'></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error in your code but in the dialog element you need to listen to `onCancel` event instead of `onClose` event.

```js
ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
      document.getElementById("root")
 );

function App() {
  const modalRef = React.createRef()
  
  function handleClose(e) { // press escape button to trigger this
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('closing')
  }
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <button 
        onClick={() => modalRef.current.showModal()}>
        Open modal
      </button>
      
      
      <dialog
        ref={modalRef}
        onCancel={handleClose}>
        Hello world
      </dialog>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: NOTE: be sure to use `showModal()` instead of `show()` in order to get both  the `cancel` event and a `::backdrop`. However, you only receive the `cancel` event in modal mode when pressing the ESC(ape) key, not when dismissed with a `form[method="dialog"] button[type="submit"]` action. The `close` event fires for both `showModal` and `show` modes regardless of whether or not it was closed using a form or the ESC key.